# Binary data handling and bitwise AND

Tags: javascript, binary, bitwise-operators

I saw this code sample without any explanation:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/path/to/image.png', true);

// Trick to pass bytes through unprocessed.
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var binStr = this.responseText;
    for (var i = 0, len = binStr.length; i < len; ++i) {
      var c = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
      //String.fromCharCode(c & 0xff)
      var byte = c & 0xff;  // byte at offset i
    }
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

I wonder what that line `var byte = c & 0xff;  // byte at offset i` is doing? Why `AND` with `0xFF`? This code is in JavaScript if that matters.

Comment: Bytes are in the range `[0, 255]`, and `& 0xff` equals `% 255` so that it returns a valid byte.

Comment: I'd suggest to read up on bitwise operators. Even if you're not gonna use them every day, they're a good thing to know, and very interesting to learn about IMO.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code appears to be storing a byte value. Apparently, the developer thought it was possible that `c` could contain more than 8 bits (a byte) of data. By `AND`ing with 0xff, any data beyond 8 bits is trimmed off (or at least set to zero).

Comment: Hmm, I see, yea now I understand it.